# Efficiently getting batches of elements from array - Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm newbie in Python and Numpy.

I have this input:

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]

And I want to get this output:

```
[
  [
    [[ 1  2  3], [ 7  8  9]],
    [[ 2  3  4], [ 8  9 10]]
  ],

  [
    [[ 4  5  6], [10 11 12]],
    [[ 5  6  7], [11 12 13]]
  ]
]
```

That array has this shape: `(n_batches, 2, batch_size, seq_length)`. In the following code you can see what means those parameters.

I did it using `for loops`. Note, the following codes is from [here](http://www.alivelearn.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/dlnd_tv_script_generation_submit2.html):

```
def get_batches(int_text, batch_size, seq_length):
    """
    Return batches of input and target
    :param int_text: Text with the words replaced by their ids
    :param batch_size: The size of batch
    :param seq_length: The length of sequence
    :return: Batches as a Numpy array
    """
    # TODO: Implement Function    
    n_batches = int(len(int_text) / batch_size / seq_length)    
    batches = np.zeros(shape = (n_batches, 2, batch_size, seq_length), dtype = np.int32)
    index = 0
    for batch_index in range(n_batches):  
        one_batch = np.zeros(shape = (2, batch_size, seq_length), dtype = np.int32)
        one_batch_seq = np.zeros(shape = (batch_size, seq_length), dtype = np.int32)
        one_batch_tar = np.zeros(shape = (batch_size, seq_length), dtype = np.int32)
        for n in range(batch_size):
            index = batch_index * seq_length + n * n_batches * seq_length            
            seq = np.array([int_text[index:index+seq_length]])
            tar = np.array([int_text[index+1:index+seq_length+1]])
            one_batch_seq[n] = seq;
            one_batch_tar[n] = tar;
            #print(seq)
            #if(one_batch_seq.size == 0):
            #    one_batch_seq = seq
            #else:
            #    one_batch_seq = np.concatenate((one_batch_seq, seq))
            #if(one_batch_tar.size == 0):
            #    one_batch_tar = tar
            #else:
            #    one_batch_tar = np.concatenate((one_batch_tar, tar))    
        one_batch[0] = one_batch_seq
        one_batch[1] = one_batch_tar
        batches[batch_index] = one_batch

    return batches
```

**Code explanation**:

I have to get how many batches I can do with that input (`int_text`). I get the value `n_batches` to know that. If you can't fill the last batch with enough data, drop the last batch.

Then, I create an array with shape `(n_batches, 2, batch_size, seq_length)`. And, after that, the loops.

But someone has told me that I can do it without loops and only using Numpy. And I don't know how to do it. I think, I can do it with reshape, but I'm not sure.

How can I get that output without using for-loop?

Comment: So, you are not using `13, 14, 15`?

Comment: @Divakar Yes. If you can't fill the last batch with enough data, drop the last batch. I have updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a super-efficient one with [`NumPy strides`](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) -

```
def get_batches_strided(a, batch_size, seq_length):
    n_batches = int(len(a) / batch_size / seq_length)   
    shp = (n_batches, 2, batch_size, seq_length)

    n = a.strides[0]
    s = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
    strides=(shp[3]*n,n,shp[0]*shp[3]*n,n)
    out = s(a, shp, strides=strides)
    return out
```

This would be a view into the input array and as such won't occupy any more of the memory space and that's the very place where it derives it efficiency as well.

Also, since we are working with `views` and also `strides` based approach would go beyond the memory allocated for the input array if the shape/strides is listed as such, we need to be careful about the input parameters to it.

Sample run to verify across various input params -

```
In [306]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

# List of values to select batch_size, seq_length to form different combinations
# of inputs to be fed to the two proposed approaches for tesing
In [308]: r = [2,3,4]

In [309]: [np.allclose(get_batches(a,m,n), get_batches_strided(a,m,n)) \
                                                    for m in r for n in r]
Out[309]: [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True] # All checked out
```

A glimpse into the performance improvements -

```
In [320]: a = np.arange(1,2001)

In [321]: %timeit get_batches(a, 3,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.87 ms per loop

In [322]: %timeit get_batches_strided(a, 3,2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.07 µs per loop
```

If we need a copy, it won't be too costly -

```
In [323]: %timeit get_batches_strided(a, 3,2).copy()
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop
```

---

**Workflow recap to decide `strides`**

With using `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`, there are just two crucial parameters - shape and strides. Shape was okay, as we would get that from the loopy version. Getting the strides was tricky and appreciable amount of trial and error went into deciding it.

Let me try to play it back for the benefit of people trying to learn/use `strides`.

The input is :

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Get the stride length and assign a shorter name to strides func :

```
n = a.strides[0]
s = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided
```

Strided approach with various combinations of strides were tested and the successful one for each input pair are listed below -

```
#get_batches(a, 2, 2) # case1
#s(a, (3,2,2,2), strides=(2*n,1*n,6*n,n)) # worked

#get_batches(a, 2, 3) # case2
#s(a, (2,2,2,3), strides=(3*n,1*n,6*n,n)) # worked

#get_batches(a, 3,4) # case3
#s(a, (1,2,3,4), strides=(4*n,1*n,4*n,n)) # worked

#get_batches(a, 3,2) # case4
#s(a, (2,2,3,2), strides=(2*n,1*n,4*n,n)) # worked
```

Next work was finding the pattern, and after few looks, it became apparent as :

```
#strides=(shp[3]*n,n,shp[0]*shp[3]*n,n), where shp is the input shape tuple
```